Why my logback-spring.xml creates two log files?
bootstrap.yml
spring:
  application:
    name: manage
  profiles:
    active: dev

logback-spring.xml
...
<springProperty scope="context" name="springAppName" source="spring.application.name"/>
...
...
<springProperty scope="context" name="logPath" source="logging.path" defaultValue="logs"/>
<appender name="file" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${logPath}/${springAppName}.log</file>
        <append>true</append>
...
</appender>

there are two log file in logs folder when this app run.
manage.log and springAppNameIS_UNDEFINED.log
I try to create a application.yml
application.yml
spring:
  application:
    name: manage
  profiles:
    active: dev

and... It works.there is just a manage.log in the logs folder.
I don't know how it's works,and How to get the correct log without application.yml.
